# Is tor the solution to being stalked through Facebook?

Tags: anonymity

I have had a stalking problem for several years.  My stalker has started setting up random Facebook accounts and sending me 'other' messages; I never respond, but I think that, just be creating that chat window, he is able to search my IP address and find out what city I am living in. I have downloaded torbrowser. If I use it to connect log-in to Facebook, will that hide my IP from detection?

Comment: As Stig Atle wrote, the answer is yes. Furthermore it might be helpful for you to use the address https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/. Facebook "thinks" you're coming from 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and sets your default location to London, England.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the Tor FAQ answers this question:

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AnonymityAndSecurity

> Generally speaking, Tor aims to solve three privacy problems:
>
> First, Tor prevents websites and other services from learning your
>   location, which they can use to build databases about your habits and
>   interests. With Tor, your Internet connections don't give you away by
>   default -- now you can have the ability to choose, for each
>   connection, how much information to reveal.
>
> Second, Tor prevents people watching your traffic locally (such as
>   your ISP) from learning what information you're fetching and where
>   you're fetching it from. It also stops them from deciding what you're
>   allowed to learn and publish -- if you can get to any part of the Tor
>   network, you can reach any site on the Internet.
>
> Third, Tor routes your connection through more than one Tor relay so
>   no single relay can learn what you're up to. Because these relays are
>   run by different individuals or organizations, distributing trust
>   provides more security than the old one hop proxy approach.